# Python: Are these the same?

Tags: python-3.x

Look at the code below and explain what it illustrates:

```
hash = { ’one’ : 1, ’two’ : 2, ’three’ : 3 }

hash = {’three’: 3, ’two’: 2, ’one’: 1}
```

Comment: doesn't illustrate much, since they're both full of syntax errors. `’` are not valid quotes - don't use microsoft word to edit your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
hash = {'one':1,'two':2,'three':3}
hash = {'three':3,'two':2,'one':1}
```

This is the correct declaration of hash (without typographical errors).
In order to get the value, you are supposed to use `hash[key]`.
Considering the above two hashes:
If you type in `hash[three]`, it will return the value `3`.
The output(`3`) remains the same in case of both the above hashes.

A hash is different from a list. In a list, you would use the index/position to get the value.

```
a = [1,2,3]
a = [3,2,1]
```

If you type in `a[0]`, the value will be different in both the cases.

But in case of hash, you are using the assigned key to access the value and therefore, it doesn't make a difference. The order doesn't matter. This is because hash functions doesn't care about the position. It works only on the basis of key/value pair.

In short, both the hashes are the same and would give the same output for a particular key.

Comment: `a = {3, 2, 1}` creates a set in Python, not an array. You might wanna use a list with square brackets instead: `a = [3, 2, 1]`

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen
I hadn't noticed it.Edited it.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you remove your obvious typographic errors, they might not necessarily be the same, but they will certainly be *indistinguishable*.

That is, there is no operation you can apply to either version that will reveal the order that the elements are inserted into the container.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are creating a dictionary which is a data structure contained from key-value pairs. What you see on the left of ":" is the key and what you see on the right of ":" is the value.
In order to get a specific value of a key you use : `hash[key]`

**There is no difference between the two lines**, because the order doesn't count when you create dictionaries since the key-value pairs are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> hash = {'three':3,'two':2,'one':1}
>>> hash1 = {'one':1,'two':2,'three':3}
>>> hash == hash1
    True
>>> type(hash) == type(hash1)
    True
>>> id(hash) == id(hash1)
    False
```

Comment: Please consider explaining your answer.